# Standard windows minesweeper - is it client-server or pure client application?

Tags: windows, client

We, with friend of mine, had a dispute. Is standard windows minesweeper is a client application or client-server?

Answer (score 8):

Neither. It's a plain old Windows application. `Client` implies there's a server somewhere (which there isn't), and `client/server` implies there's a server in the mix somewhere (which there isn't).